# How to Cite Unpublished Court Orders

Tags: legal-research

I have looked for this online, but have come up with inconsistent results. Here is one example from California:

> *Tsukroff v. Hedgeside Property & Inv. Co.*, California Superior Court, Napa County, case no. 26-25117 (order dated 01/19/05) (unpublished)

Can anyone confirm if this is correct? Since courts differ in their rules from one state to another, please provide several examples. If Bluebook has a point of view on this, I'd appreciate it if you would share that as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Federal Court's we's normally do something like:

*Tsukroff v. Hedgeside Property & Inv. Co.*, No. 26-25117, Order (COURT ABBREVIATION, Jan. 19, 2005).

Comment: Thanks for your response. What does "COURT ABBREVIATION" signify?

Comment: Whatever the standard abbreviation is for the court in question. I don't the table handy but it's something like "Cal. Super. Ct."